# Difficulty implementing PUT annotation in my Rest service

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, maven

I am using Java,Maven,Hibernate 3/JPA ,Eclipse to implement a PUT method for populating a Mysql db.

Here is my POJO

```
 import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
    import java.util.Date;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
    import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Person", catalog = "mydb", uniqueConstraints = {
                        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "Person"),})
    public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String Name;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getName() {
    return flowName;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
    }

    }
```

Here is my annotations class.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.tracker.domain.Flow;
    import com.tracker.persistence.HibernateUtil;

    public class PersonService {
    private Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TrackerService.class);

    String JsonString = "{\"name\":\"John Doe\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Person person = gson.fromJson(JsonString,Person.class);

    @PUT
    @Path("")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void processandSaveJson(Person person) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    String Name = Person.getName();
    person.setName(Name);
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(person);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    }
```

Here is my Hibernate.Util.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

    public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

    try {
    // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
    return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {

    // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    }



 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
    }
    }
```

Here is my SessionFactory Context Listener class

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
    import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.hibernate.Session;

    @WebListener
    public class SessionFactoryListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SessionFactoryListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
    LOG.info("\n\tInside contextInitialized()---\n");
    }

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
    LOG.info("\n\tInside contextDestroyed()\n");
    }

    HibernateUtil.shutdown();   
    }   

    }
```

When I try to run this using Tomcat Server, i get the following error.

```
type Status report
message Method Not Allowed
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

I am very new to this. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong. I trying to insert a 
record into a mysql db using the above values. Kindly help me out.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Format your code properly and make sure it all shows in your question as code. That's unreadable.

Comment: you need to show us how are you calling your method

Comment: Not sure if you copy/pasted or retyped all your code into the question, but you have some compile and logic errors. You also didn't provide a valid @Path for your resource class. What JAX-RS provider are you using?

Comment: Hello,thank you all for your inputs. @Ryan, I hope this code is now readable. I am trying to call this from a browser by issuing the command : http://localhost:8080/Person. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong since I am very new to this topic. Thanks you all for your help.

Comment: 1) The code is no better. Put it into an IDE and auto-format it at least. 2) A browser doesn't do PUTs.

Comment: You might have a look at one of the many REST tutorials [suggested by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rest+tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments, you should supply your calling code along with the rest. but since you already mentioned that you're using a browser to make the request, it should be mentioned that most/no browsers support 'put' without using javadcript. what you are doing looks like a simple 'get'.
so the solution is to either use javascript in your form submission, or discard REST and have Urls that reflect the method (eg. /person/new/ and /person/{personId}